# Import fails silently

Tags: import, memory, csv-format

In brief, an `Import` of a largish (11G) tsv file fails silently.  I'm looking for ways to troubleshoot the problem further, and/or work around the failure.

---

**Details**

The machine I'm using has more than enough memory to handle such a large file.  Below is a summary of the available memory before I start *Mathematica*:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G       1.5G        29G       6.1M        47M       298M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.2G        30G
Swap:          15G       2.9G        12G
```

I start a fresh *Mathematica* session, and type in the expression shown below:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Note that at this point the word `matrix` is colored blue, indicating that the `matrix` is as-yet undefined.)

I then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, upon which

- the cell's bracket changes from thin blue to thick black, and
- the prefix "Running... " appears before the window's title in the notebook's title bar,

...and remain this way for several minutes.

Eventually the cell's bracket's appearance reverts to its initial state, and the "Running... " prefix disappears from the window's title bar, but the notebook's appearance remains otherwise unchanged.

In particular,

- the color of the word `matrix` remains as it was before the evaluation;
- no messages of any kind are visible.

There are no messages in the Messages window (available through the menu command `Windows` > `Messages`), and no dialog window ever pops up.

IOW, the evaluation appears to have failed, but there's no explicit mention of this fact.

At this point, `MaxMemoryUsed[]` reports ~33MB (32612736 bytes, to be precise), a minuscule amount.  (The kernel probably crashed during evaluation, so this figure is not very informative.)  Indeed, the machine's memory usage now is not very different from what it was before:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G       1.6G        29G       5.6M        24M       264M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.3G        30G
Swap:          15G       2.9G        12G
```

---

FWIW, other programs I use regularly (e.g. MATLAB, ipython, python, perl, R, etc.) can handle this file without much problem.

**Q:** How can I troubleshoot the problem further?

**Q:** How can I get *Mathematica* to import this file?

Comment: How much memory do you have in the computer?  32GB?  I am a bit skeptical if M would be able to read such a huge tsv file and fit the result into memory.  It won't even be a packed array. And even if it could read the file, it would probably take ages ...  Of course I would love to be proven wrong about this.

Comment: @Szabolcs: yes, 32GB is what I have here.

Comment: They say a better importer is coming in 11.2 http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1059289

Comment: @Szabolcs: the information in the link you posted (and in pages linked therein) is really troubling...  The larger the data, the easier it is to miss corruptions like the ones described in several of those posts.  Yikes.

Comment: Do you need all the data contained on the file at the same time? I suggest to `OpenRead` and go line by line (`ReadLine`) parsing only the relevant information as needed in a way that can give you a hint where the readout fails. If its is because of memory, the reading order should not matter, if the file is corrupted, the location should be consistent.

Comment: whats in the file? If all numbers for example it may be better to use `ReadList` anyway

Comment: Could you please share the file somehow?

Comment: @GenericAccountName: Unfortunately, that file, as well as with the instance of *Mathematica* I was using, belong to my former employer, and I no longer have access to them.